# WPF passing a bind to my User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a simple UserControl that has a `Value` property:

```
public partial class Label : UserControl
{
    public Label()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(Label), new PropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

And I'm using this XAML:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#A0A0A0" BorderThickness="1, 1, 0, 0" CornerRadius="1">
    <Border BorderBrush="#000000" BorderThickness="0, 0, 1, 1" CornerRadius="1">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5, 0" EndPoint="0.5, 1">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#E0E0E0" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <TextBlock Width="100" FontWeight="SemiBold" Padding="2" Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </Border>
</Border>
```

This works when I set the value explicity like this:

```
<uc:Label Value="Name" />
```

But for some reason it doesn't when I try to use a bind:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding InfoDetran}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Doesn't work -->
                <uc:Label Value="{Binding Label}" />
                <!-- But this works -->
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Label}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `Value` property of my userControl isn't being updated and I am getting a binding error: `BindingExpression path error: 'Label' property not found on 'object' ''Label' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Label; DataItem='Label' (Name=''); target element is 'Label' (Name=''); target property is 'Value' (type 'Object')`

What is this `object` it is looking for the property on, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of your items (in `InfoDetran`)? Do they have a `Label` property?

Comment: @MártonMolnár Yes, it's a string property. The type is a regular ModelView. Basically it is a collection of labels that I want displayed in the form (such as `Name`, `Age`, etc), they appear fine on regular controls but not on my user control.

Comment: Is the textbox working?

Comment: @aggietech Yes the Label's value shows fine on the TextBox.

Comment: Could the issue be in the Dependency property? Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(Label), new PropertyMetadata("")) ... typeof(Label) can be confusing.

Comment: Change your `Value` `DependencyProperty` type to `string` instead of `object` and see if that works. Might be just a mismatch.

Comment: Try not setting the DataContext to this ... it should inherit from the parent. See my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DataContext` is being inherited from the parent which wipes out your manual setter.

You could fix this by changing the XAML to bind the content's `DataContext` to that of the control itself, then the bindings will carry on working as the inherited context is always the `UserControl` itself:

```
<UserControl ...
             x:Name="Root">
    <Border DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Root}"  BorderBrush="#A0A0A0" BorderThickness="1, 1, 0, 0" CornerRadius="1">
        <Border BorderBrush="#000000" BorderThickness="0, 0, 1, 1" CornerRadius="1">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5, 0" EndPoint="0.5, 1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#E0E0E0" Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <TextBlock Width="100" FontWeight="SemiBold" Padding="2" Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </Border>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Note I've named the control with `x:Name="Root"` and bound the `Border` context as `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Root}"`.

You can remove `DataContext = this` from the code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Could the issue be with the DP? 
If you rename the Label to something else, will it fix the issue?
Also, you probably need not to over-write the data context ... it should inherit
from its parent control since you are binding the parent's property to it.

```
public partial class CustomLabel : UserControl
{
    public CustomLabel ()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(CustomLabel), new PropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

Comment: If I remove the `DataContext = this;` line from the UserControl, the explicit values stops working as well. From what I've read I'm supposed to specify which DataContext the property is from and either I use the control itself or the `RelativeSource` on every bind (which would make the XAML worse imo). I tried renaming the Label but it didn't work.

Comment: `<TextBlock Width="100" FontWeight="SemiBold" Padding="2" Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />` will fix that issue in your `UserControl` XAML

Comment: Good catch @FrankJ - i didn't pay attention to that part of the xaml.

Comment: @Daniichi with all those changes combined (remove DataContext in code behind, changing the property type and binding to the `TemplatedParent` in the `UserControl`) does it work now?

Comment: @FrankJ Nope, removing the DataContext line doesn't bind any value at all, even with the RelativeSource line added. I tested outside the collection as well and explicit strings, none worked.